# Exported glTF file includes more data than it should

Tags: animation, gltf

I imported a glTF file in blender that has a model & armature (no animations)
Then I created a very simple animation (Just 2 keyframes) where i **only** rotated a bone and then exported to glTF.
After that I checked the channels of the animation and saw that targets included 'translation' and 'scale' paths even though the animation only consisted of rotating a bone, why is that?
the translation I can maybe understand(perhaps it sets the rotation origin for each bone, just a guess though) but scale makes no sense(I also checked the scale values and all of them are 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 or 1.0, 0.9999994, 1.0 etc) what I expected was only targets with the 'rotation' path

Blender file: [image]

Update: It seems like disabling "Always sample animations" fixes this (it also only exports the keyframes I created instead of all the inbetween ones as well) as for why this works I'm not sure yet.

Comment: You may have **only** rotated the bone, but your blend file shows that you actually set the keyframes for location, rotation and scale so that's what got exported! How did you actually set the keyframes in Blender? Pressing 'I' and selecting 'Rotation' from the popup menu just adds the rotation keyframes.

Comment: I used the 'record' option then selected the keyframe and used the 'rotate' gizmo to rotate the bone.

Comment: Gif of me doing it again: https://i.imgur.com/K3KSYEK.gif

Comment: Also i don't see location, scale keyframes in blender(at least they are not modified) only rotation is changing https://i.imgur.com/NFQGWXE.gif

Comment: The 'record' option will **always** create keyframes for location, rotation and scale even if location and scale haven't changed! That's why I said use the 'I' key to save just the keyframes you need. You can also save just a single keyframe if (for instance) you've just moved the X location by right-clicking the changed value and selecting 'Single keyframe' in the popup menu.

Comment: In Blender 3.0, if I delete the Loc/Scale fcurves (in the Dope Sheet), and then export, I get a glTF with only a rotation channel.

Comment: @securest Best to do it right in the first place rather than having to fiddle around deleting unwanted keyframes later! :^)

Comment: Yeah using 'I' seems better but for some reason when i press 'I' then 'rotation' then set the rotation it's never 'saved' for some reason. that's why i've always used the record key

Comment: Nevermind, im still very new blender and i simply had to first do the rotation and then press 'I' and rotation :)

Comment: After using 'i' to only add rotation i still get scale and translation targets in the glTF file:
Steps:
1) Set the keyframe time(15)
2) Rotate the bone using the rotation gizmo
3) Press 'I' and select Rotation
4) Set the keyframe time(30)
5) Rotate the bone using the rotation gizmo
6) Press 'I' and select rotation
7) Export to glTF Embedded

Comment: @JohnEason when you said 'just adds the rotation keyframes' did you only check in blender or also the glTF file because i also only see rotation keyframes in blender but translation, scale ones in the glTF file

Comment: @Suic What Blender version are you testing with? Like I said, it works for me in current Blender 3.0, but it will not work in 2.93 or earlier.

Comment: I'm using blender 2.93.6 i believe, whichever one was the latest in blenders download page, I did not even know 3 existed, did they fix the issue I'm describing in blender 3? @scurest I will test with 3 tomorrow

Comment: Blender 3 is still in beta and isn't officially released until next month (December). I'm using the same version as you (2.93.6) but don't know anything about gltf files. My observations were about your uploaded Blend file and, since the dope sheet showed keyframes for location and scale as well as rotation, I assume that's what appeared in the exported file. Did you deleted all the keyframes and set just the rotation before exporting again? - If you just set a rotation keyframe it won't delete the already set location and scale ones.

Comment: yes @JohnEason I re-did the simple animation from scratch (only adding rotation keyframes) the issue is still represent, it however is fixed in blender 3.0(RC)

Comment: Glad you found the answer! Hopefully that will be fixed in 2.93.7 since bugs are still being fixed in that version.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this is an issue present in blender 2.93.6 and is fixed in Blender 3.0(RC) the 'fix(that worked for me)' in 2.93.6 was to disable 'Always sample animations' when exporting to glTF.

Comment: Be very careful disabling that.  The animation system in glTF does not match 1:1 everything that Blender's animation system does.  In particular, the way rotations are interpolated in glTF can be quite different from Blender's rotation interpolation options.  That's why the default was chosen to be "Always sample," it writes more data into the file but it more faithfully reproduces the intended animation.

Comment: oh i was not aware of that, what exactly does the "Always sample animations" do? @emackey

Comment: Essentially it "bakes" the animations, turning every frame into a keyframe, applying linear interpolation between them.  Complex curves can be approximated and reproduced even on systems that don't offer Blender's flexible animation options.

Comment: I see, well in blender 3.0(RC) i have that option toggled on and it works properly now(doesn't export translation/scale keyframes if i only have rotation ones) it also by the looks of it exports the keyframes that were actually affected instead of keyframes for every single bone(which did happen previously)

Comment: If you need to, CLI tools can remove the unneeded keyframes after export. Example: `gltf-transform resample input.glb output.glb`([docs](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/cli.html))

Comment: I will check it out, thanks @DonMcCurdy